# Apple developer one app_id/provisioning per app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I'm developing an app which I will duplicate to many clients. Each client will have one app on Apple Store.

For each version (each client) of this application do I need to create a new app_id/provisioning or can I use the same app_id/provisioning?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need a different App ID for each application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a wildcard then you don't need to have a different app ID and provisioning profile. That is unless you want to use push notifications for example in which case you will need a specific app ID for each app.

That's assuming you're releasing the apps under a single developer account, of course. Multiple developer accounts then obviously you would need multiple app IDs and provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your app does, and what your future plans for the app are.

If you don't do push notifications AND don't use iCloud you can use a wild card as opposed to an app iD for each app.

Having an app ID & provisioning profile per app is cheap (as in no money).

Having a developer account per app would cost money, but if you ever want to sell an app (and the app's user base) independently of your other applications you will need to do that.   Otherwise you will either sever the code from the user base when you sell it, or forever have to take code from the buyer and submit it to Apple on their behalf.